# Make checkbox by QAbstractTableModel

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to make the first column with checkbox, and get the check status of that, how can I do that? I override the flag(), but it seems do not work, I am sure where is the problem?

And I got this [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121537/how-to-make-qabstracttablemodel-s-data-checkable), but it does work for my code either. And I don't want to use delegate, because it is too complicated.

```
data = [['00','01','02'],
         ['10','11','12'],
         ['20','21','22']]

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        clipTableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.model = TModel(data, self)
        clipTableView = QTableView()
        clipTableView.setModel(self.model)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(clipTableView)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class TModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, datain, parent=None):
        super(TModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.arraydata = datain

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.arraydata)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.arraydata[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QVariant()
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()
        return QVariant(self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()])

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QVariant()
        elif index.column() == 1:
            return Qt.ItemIsSelectable|Qt.ItemIsEnabled|Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
        return QVariant()
```

Comment: The problem here is that you are not using items to store your data, as the flag say's its a Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable . It requires an item to implement this characteristic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the solution to your problem. The reason Why your flags weren't working is because those flags dont work on text , they are meant for QItems .

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *    
import sys

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        data = [['00','01','02'],
         ['10','11','12'],
         ['20','21','22']]
        clipTableWidget = QTableWidget()

        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        clipTableView = QTableView()
        count1=0
        for row in data:
            count2 = 0
            for column in row:
                if count2 == 0:
                    item = QStandardItem(column)
                    item.setCheckable(True)
                    item.setCheckState(False)
                    item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable| Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                    self.model.setItem(count1,count2,item)
                    count2+=1
                else:
                    item = QStandardItem(column)
                    self.model.setItem(count1,count2,item)
                    count2+=1
            count1+=1


        clipTableView.setModel(self.model)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(clipTableView)
        self.setLayout(layout)

def main(): 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    w = MainWindow() 
    w.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) 


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```